# RedisConnectionException occurs after running the Linux deployment project

Tags: linux, asp.net-core

I'm testing a simple project deployment, but after deploying it, the project has this error.I'm testing a simple project deployment, but I'm getting errors like the following in StackExchange.Redis when running.

```
StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s); to create a disconnected multiplexer, disable AbortOnConnectFail. Timeout
   at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.Conne
```

What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you get usually indicates that you didn't set **abortConnect=false** in the connection string.

The default value of *abortConnect* is **true**, which makes StackExchange.Redis not automatically reconnect to the server in some cases.

It is recommended that you set **abortConnect=false** in your connection string.

In addition, because StackExchange.Redis uses a single thread, if a request takes too long, subsequent requests will be blocked, increasing the request timeout limit.

You can try to use csredis to replace the driver：

https://github.com/2881099/csredis